# Oauth 2.0 between own server and mobile client

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am developing a application with mobile client using node.js platform with passport module. I was thinking of implementing Oauth 2.0 for authentication from mobile to server. I am not able to understand what app id to give to the mobile-client. I also want to make sure that I am able to differentiate if the user logged in using a different mobile to the one he had logged in before.

Answer (score 1):

The appId will be dependent on what passport service you are using.  If you are using facebook  or twitter you will have to go to either developer.facebook.com or developer.twitter.com and setup an app.  This will be the id is needed.  More specifically, for twitter you need

twitter-consumer-key
twitter-consumer-secret
twitter-callback

and facebook you need

facebook-client-id
facebook-client-secret
facebook-callback

You would then authenticate the user.  After authentication you could make a call to your server to pass in the mobile device or any other information you want to track.  The keys would not need to be stored on the mobile devices, the mobile devices would just need to call an endpoint on your server to handle the authentication.

Comment: I am sorry you got me wrong, Its not to consume others Oauth service for authentication rather to build an Oauth based authentication service for my own servers

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I think app id is arbitrary as far as it is your own. As you can see in [client.js](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize/blob/master/examples/express2/db/clients.js) from [oauth2orize example](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize/tree/master/examples/express2), it's just "abc123".

Please take a look at [this section of "The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2) for more information.